# Free code coverage tools in .NET for personal project

Tags: .net, code-coverage

I need a free code coverage tools in .NET for personal project. NCover is bit expensive for person use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Discontinued versions of NCover are still free (and still work quite well, in my opinion). Get them [here](http://www.ncover.com/download/discontinued).

UPDATE (20th Nov, 2012): I believe [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) is now the best option. I've used it with great success on my current .NET 4 project.

Answer (score 8):

**OpenCover** is the successor of PartCover and actively developed (as of feb. 2013).
Find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) or install as a [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/opencover).

From the creator of both products:

> NOTE: PartCover is now in Maintenance mode (fixes only) all new development is being done on OpenCover which now has 32/64 bit support and also supports branch as well as sequence coverage.

You may also wish to use **ReportGenerator** to get human-friendly reports.
Available on [Codeplex](http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com/) and also as a [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/ReportGenerator).

As far as I can tell, it's the reporting part that lags behind commercial offerings, lacking custom aggregation/drill-down abilities, but it's certainly usable.

Comment: I give you a +1 because it's a very good answer. I don't understand why someone would downvote this...

Answer (score 4):

give PartCover a try, but i dont know if it works with .Net 3.x !
[PartCover download on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/partcover/)

Comment: Partcover is now maintained on GitHub https://github.com/sawilde/opencover and there is a new tool called OpenCover https://github.com/sawilde/opencover

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple Visual Studio extension for OpenCover, while it is somewhat barebones as of now it looks and works much better than the other free solutions I have found. Also I made it free under MIT license, so you can use it / modify it as needed. It is called AxoCover and you can download it from Visual Studio, or [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=axodox1.AxoCover). Source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/axodox/AxoTools).