# Open source code coverage tool for .net that can be integrated with cc net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, code-coverage

Can u please tell me any code coverage tool name that i can use in cruise control .net,

Is part cover is open source or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free code coverage tools in .NET for personal project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468930/free-code-coverage-tools-in-net-for-personal-project)

Comment: that's OK but i asked that part cover is open source or not

Comment: I want to use OpenCover in CC net Web Dashboard. So it will display Code Coverage per build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) and [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) are both open source code coverage tools that can be integrated into build automation systems such as CC.NET.

With both you can use [ReportGenerator](http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com/) to display results; though PartCover does come with it's own viewer I prefer to use the ReportGenerator one myself as the HTML can be integrated quite nicely into a build status report.

You may also build your own reports using XSLT or such like as both tools have an XML output.

Comment: Could u tell me how to integrate OpenCover with CC.net and MSTest or any Link that will describe how to use this.

Comment: I don't use CC.NET what does it use for scripting NANT?

Comment: Please can anybody tell me how to configure OpenCover With CC net with MsTest

Comment: Now my OpenCover Working Fine but i want to display coverage report build by build. Please tell me how can i do this

Comment: At least tell me from where i can download  OpenCover XSLT File.

Comment: As I said I use [ReportGenerator](http://reportgenerator.codeplex.com/) to turn the XML into HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can merge OpenCover output with log file and by using XSLT u can show Code coverage build by build.

```
<publishers>
  <merge>
    <files>         
      <file>yourPath\coverage.xml</file>

    </files>
  </merge>
```